# Docker-compose database table reset

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, yaml, dockerfile

I am new to docker technology. I use docker-compose in my project and every time I start docker-compose my database tables are reset.

**docker-compose.yaml**

```
version: '3'
services:

  #PHP Service
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/php/Dockerfile
    image: php-7.4.1-extended
    container_name: php
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    environment:
      SERVICE_NAME: app
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./docker/php/local.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/local.ini
    networks:
      - app-network

  #Nginx Service
  webserver:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: nginx
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./docker/nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
    networks:
      - app-network
      
  #MySQL Service
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7.22
    container_name: mysql
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_USER: root
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: root
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
      SERVICE_NAME: mysql
    volumes:
      - ./docker/mysql/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf
    networks:
      - app-network
#Docker Networks
networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge
#Volumes
volumes:
  dbdata:
    driver: local
```

I found an example of docker-compose.yaml file from some sources and made changes on it. What should I do to fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your docker image is storing its data within the image, which isn't persisted. You need to tell Docker to store the data on a volume, instead. This is a bit version-dependent, but something like

```
 #MySQL Service
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7.22
    container_name: mysql
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_USER: root
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: root
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
      SERVICE_NAME: mysql
    volumes:
       - ./docker/mysql/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf
       - "./.mysql-data/db:/var/lib/mysql"
```

And then delete

```
 dbdata:
    driver: local
```